# SerializationException: Error serializing Avro message

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, apache-kafka-streams, confluent-platform

I'm using KStreams which have a AVRO schema and are hooked up with the schema registry. When I start processing the stream, I get a `NullPointerException` as follows:

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error serializing Avro message
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null of int in field SCORE_THRSHLD_EXCD of gbl_au_avro
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.npe(GenericDatumWriter.java:145)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.writeWithoutConversion(GenericDatumWriter.java:139)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.write(GenericDatumWriter.java:75)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.write(GenericDatumWriter.java:62)
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.serializeImpl(AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.java:92)
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer.serialize(KafkaAvroSerializer.java:53)
    at io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.avro.GenericAvroSerializer.serialize(GenericAvroSerializer.java:63)
    at io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.avro.GenericAvroSerializer.serialize(GenericAvroSerializer.java:39)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordCollectorImpl.send(RecordCollectorImpl.java:154)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordCollectorImpl.send(RecordCollectorImpl.java:98)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SinkNode.process(SinkNode.java:89)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:143)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:126)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:90)
```

Not sure what the issue is here. Both source and sink have schema repository linked to them and have schemas defined correctly.

Can you please suggest what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Can you provide the entity's schema and an example of avro message?

Comment: Thanks for your response! I was writing to a topic without filling in the entire Avro record. My bad.